# Bean definition and name-lookup

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to experen=ment with [spring's name lookup](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection):

```
<bean id="test" class="com.badmitrii.TestBean" />

<bean id="anotherTest" class="com.badmitrii.AnotherTestBean">
    <lookup-method bean="test" name="getString"/>
</bean>

public class TestBean {

    private String testBean = "Test bean";

    //GET, SET

    public String getString(){
        return "String";
    }
}

public class AnotherTestBean {

    private String testBean = "Another test bean";

    //GET, SET

    public String getString(){
        return "Overriden string";
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to run the application I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pac.TestBean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.pac.AnotherTestBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d6d0f4c6.getString(<generated>)
```

on the line:

```
System.out.println(((AnotherTestBean) context.getBean("anotherTest")).getString());
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that the bean "anotherTest" is of type `com.badmitrii.AnotherTestBean`, and is created by calling the method `getString()` of the bean `test`.

But this method doesn't return an instance of `com.badmitrii.AnotherTestBean`. It returns a String. Hence the exception.

Comment: I thought, it was supposed to just override the implementation of `getString` with `TestBean`'s method. So in fact, `lookup-method` is to moving method's implementation to the spring-config, huh?

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean.